# What are the "must have" jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'd like to know what are the most useful JQuery plugins. I'm particularly interested in  those which are likely to be useful in general UI development, such as [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com), rather than those which serve uncommon needs.

If you could provide a very brief description of the plugin's purpose, that would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Lot of people tend to combine jquery with good ui libraries like YUI or dojo . This makes it easy to skin the app and gives a consistent look across the board, which could be quite diffcult to achieve with hodge-podge of jquery plugins for  UI . My 2C :)

Comment: If you are using dojo or YUI, then you might aswell not use jQuery because both includes similar javascript library like jQuery.

Comment: jQuery + YUI + dojo + the "must have" plugins, yeaaah. I'm pretty sure I'll never hit your site in a lifetime.

Answer (score 45):

My list:

- [Autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

  - Input field to enable users quickly finding and selecting some value, leveraging searching and filtering.
- [JSON](http://mg.to/2006/01/25/json-for-jquery)

  - JSON plugin retrieving retrieving and manipulating json data.
- [Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie)

  - Simple & lightweight utility plugin for reading, writing and deleting cookies.
- [Vaildation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

  - For validating form input data.
- [UI](http://ui.jquery.com/)

  - Full-featured themable and ready-to-use widgets and more...
- [Interface](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins:Interface)

  - Dragging, Sortables, Droppables, plug-and-play components and visual effects.
- [Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)

  - Versatile and lightweight image slideshow plugin.

Comment: If someone could try and provide a very brief description of those that have not already been described in other posts, I'll try and roll them all into a summarizing post.

Comment: Interface is depreciated and no longer works with 1.2.6 - superseeded by the UI

Comment: From JSON link: Update 2007-09-13: As of version 1.2, the jQuery core now supports cross-domain JSONP downloads as part of the native Ajax support. I suggest you use this support instead of the plugin.

Answer (score 31):

We currently use:

Most impressive

- [Layout (dock, pin, splitter) - just amazing](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html#)

Jquery UI elements:

- [Tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) - tabbed UI
- [AutoComplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) - suggestion box from web service
- [DatePicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) - nice calendar date picker

Useful community plugins:

- [Scrollable](http://www.flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html) - scrolls any div
- [Scrollpane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) - control scrollbar appearance
- [Table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) - table sorting (client-side) for any simple table
- [QuickSearch](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/quicksearch/) - instant searching of table content
- [Validate](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) - form validation (required / type / custom regEx)
- [HotKeys](http://jshotkeys.googlepages.com/test-static-01.html) - traps for key shortcuts. Captures EVERY key on the keyboard. Awesome.
- [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos) - awesome modal dialogs
- [Curvy Corners](http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html) - anti-aliased by default
- [Tokenised input (or Facebook autocomplete with Xs)](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/) - Facebook style tokenised autocomplete

More to come, I'll add links etc...

Comment: Defo - HotKeys is amazing. Also great way out for submit/enter buttons etc as well as keyboard productivity 
shortcuts

Answer (score 29):

I think that [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) plugin (a plotting library / plugin) deserves a place in this "must-have" list.

In addition, it is used here, in StackOverflow, to display the histogram of the reputation in the user account page.

Comment: That is pretty impressive - I thought those we're images the first time I saw them.

Comment: +1 Wow, Flot is pretty cool. Good find!

Comment: Used flot in a lot of projects, easily configurable and very easy to understand how it works - its a must-have!

Answer (score 11):

I'll list one I'm working on...

[My jLINQ plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jLINQ) is a jQuery version of .NET LINQ. It's made for working with in-memory collections (not talking directly to the server) and let's you use syntax similar to the following.

```
var results = $.from(data)
    .ignoreCase()
    .startsWith("firstName","m")
    .or("n")
    .isNot("administrator")
    .orderBy("lastName")
    .select();
```

It supports a bunch of other commands that you find in LINQ for ordering and grouping along with most of the selection commands like contains, between, greaterThan, etc...

[Here is a demo](http://www.hugoware.net/jLINQ) - **It's stable, but still in progress**

Maybe not must have, but might be useful as it progresses...

Comment: I know nothing about .Net so probably shouldn't even be commenting but....I believe that LINQ is a means of accessing data (relational, XML, etc.), isn't this the kind of thing that you generally wouldn't want in your client-side code, where anyone could modify it?

Comment: LINQ let's you also work with in-memory objects and arrays. That's all this is for. It doesn't actually talk to databases on the server side.

Comment: So, typically you would use it to navigate through data stored in JS objects?

Comment: Right, it's handy for working with arrays of objects. You can query the properties on the objects.

Comment: Great, I'll check out the docs if I've any further questions.

Answer (score 10):

I just found [jqGrid](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm) and it looks very good.

and it also has lots of documentation (right now a [99 pages pdf](http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgriddocs.pdf)) and [examples](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Answer (score 8):

- jQuery UI

  - For Tabs, sortable lists, custom animations, drag and drop, etc.
- AJAX Form (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

  - Changes your forms so they submit an AJAX request.
- Cycle (http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)

  - For creating carousels, or an area which cycles through an array of data (images, text, etc)
- Validation (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

  - For validating form input.

Comment: Great answer, I'd accept it, but I suppose this isn't really the kind of question that has a "right" answer and I don't want to discourage further responses (yet).

Answer (score 6):

For an unobtrusive way to send messages to the client without affecting the page's content permanently, I use [jGrowl](http://www.stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html), based on the OSX Growl system.

Lot's of options, settings, and it keeps the page clean : )

Comment: Love Growl and this looks great too.

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery tools from Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/tools/) is really fancy. I really like the expose and overlay plugin.

Comment: Agree, these often overpower jquery-ui and come with none "do whatever you want" license.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post but, just thought I would throw my 2 cents in, for future reference.

[Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) - Definitely the best modal window/lightbox for Jquery.

The Validation plugin (previously mentioned) also works very well.

Answer (score 3):

[UI](http://ui.jquery.com/) - no better way to do draggables, resizables and few others.

[Slibox2](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) - ultimate lightbox clone for jQuery, very easy to use.

[iFixPng](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iFixPng2) - simple solution for IE6 PNG w/alpha.

Answer (score 3):

I have been very impressed with the Filament Group's [Date Range Picker](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/)

Answer (score 2):

[UI](http://ui.jquery.com/) is definitely a must-have.
As a grid component, I would recommend [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). IMHO, it is better than [flexiGrid](http://www.webplicity.net/flexigrid/).

Answer (score 2):

I always use [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) to display pop-up forms and messages to the user. It keeps the UI clean (most of our users use Facebook), and yet it's not as bland as using `alert()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio 2008 to code your jQuery you need the Intellisense:
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/10/27/jquery-intellisense-documentation-file-available.aspx

Comment: You dont need it, just a nice to have:)

Comment: If you're doing jQuery in VS 2008 I think it's a must-have ;)

Comment: This is for old visual studio and for old jquery. How to use intellisence in VS2010 with lates jquery 1.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/dimensions , it has great offset and outerwith functions...

Answer (score 1):

[edit] - Recently I've been using JQuery Tools as an alternative to JQueryUI, JQuery Tools is more HTML5/CSS3 centric: http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html

I like JCarousel Lite (not JCarousel) http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/ does just what I need and nothing more.

-fs

Answer (score 1):

No one has mentioned these, which I found very usefull:

- [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) - Add advanced functions and interaction controls to a HTML table
- [BeautyTips](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) - Add configurable tooltips to a HTML element

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [jTemplates](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/), which gives you client side templating. I find it extremely powerful, especially for rendering results.

Answer (score 0):

- Jqgrid: http://www.trirand.com/blog ,**Best grid plug-in available for jQuery**
- pngFix: http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix ,**fixing problems with alpha transparent PNG images in IE**